# func_get_args() parameter list usage

Tags: php

PHP's [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) docs mention:

> This function can now be used in parameter lists.

Can anyone explain what that means and how to apply it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to 5.3 it was impossible to do this:

```
function foo($a,$b)
{
   var_dump(func_get_args());
}
```

In order to retrieve a function's arguments (i.e. for debugging purposes), you had to assign `func_get_args` return value to a variable before the actual value could be used:

```
function foo($a,$b)
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    var_dump($args);
}
```

Using the immediate return value of `func_get_args` (without a temporary variable)  is possible as of PHP 5.3.

Comment: +1 _[Note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php#refsect1-function.func-get-args-notes): Because this function depends on the current scope to determine parameter details, it cannot be used as a function parameter in versions prior to 5.3.0. If this value must be passed, the results should be assigned to a variable, and that variable should be passed._

Comment: Thanks—I get it. The "parameter lists" wording had me confused. I was wrongfully guessing it related to typehints rather than just simply meaning it could be passed as a parameter.